# mariadb access outer column in subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery

I have an issue with the following query that it is working on Mariadb 10.1.48 but it is not on 10.2.40.

It returns the following error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c.id' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT 
    p.id AS pid, 
    p.name AS pname, 
    c.id AS cid, 
    c.contract_code AS contr_code, 
    c.type AS ctype, 
    e.id AS eid, 
    e.state AS estate, 
    e.pay_code AS epay_code, 
    COUNT(z.id) AS damages, 
    rp.id AS resp_id, 
    rp.name AS resp_name, 
    rp.surname AS resp_surname, 
    IF(CURDATE() BETWEEN DATE_ADD(e.starts_pay_date, INTERVAL 23 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(e.starts_pay_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND e.state = 1, 1, 0) AS ending 
FROM `contracts` AS c,
    `customers` AS p,
    `cash` AS e
LEFT JOIN `damage` z ON e.contract_id = z.contract_id AND z.state = 1 
LEFT JOIN `customers` rp ON rp.id = ( 
    SELECT MAX(p1.id) resp 
    FROM `customers` AS p1, 
        `contract_responsible` AS r 
    WHERE c.id = r.contract_id AND p1.id = r.resp_id ) 
WHERE e.starts_pay_date <= '2021-09-08 23:59:59' AND c.customer_id = p.id AND e.contract_id = c.id 
GROUP BY e.id 
ORDER BY e.inserted_date DESC 
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

I know that it has to do with accessing outer column in a subquery, but I cannot understand why it used to work and now it is NOT!
Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: Don't mix cross-products and explicit `JOIN`.  It doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: ouff that cross join !!

Comment: I think the problem is that it's only joining with `cash`, you can't reference `contracts` or `customers` in the subquery.

Comment: Why do you have `ORDER BY` in a subquery query that just returns `MAX(p1.id)`? There's only one row, no need to order it.

Comment: Another micro optimization `IF({expression}, 1, 0)` is the same as `{expression}`

Comment: Yes, Barmar the ORDER BY there is no need to be there. I forgot it from when I executed the subquery separately. Do you know why the subquery does not work in the later MariaDB? How can I rewrite that in order for the subquery to work.